# Creating Even White-Space around Equations (Align Environment) as a Global Option

Tags: spacing, equations, formatting, align, white-space

I would like to be able to set the vertical spacing around an align environment globally. The aim would be to have the same space above and below the equations in the align environment, regardless of the spacing the equation takes up.  I would like for the spacing to always be the same, but I believe this will take some work to make a global option (either in a cls file or the preamble is fine with me).

A MWE example follows where equation 1 has different space above and below. Also equations 2 and 3 have different spacing as a whole than equations 4 and 5. I would like for all of the red lines (added to picture for clarity) to be the same length.
[image: Red Lines Should be Equal in Length]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\doublespace
asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj asldkfj alsdkjf alkdfj;lasdfiwe;q  a;sdljf; asknvc covhoienr asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj a;sdljf; lsdkjf alkdfj;lasdfiwe;q  a;sdljf; asknvc covhoienr asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj asldkfj alsdkjf alkdfj;lasdfiwe;q  a;sdljf; asknvc covhoienr 
\begin{align}
Pr(X^* = x^*, Y^* = y^* &| X=x, Y=y, C =c) \nonumber \\
    &= \sum_{y=0}^{y=1} \sum_{x=0}^{x=1} 
          Pr(y^*|y)Pr(x^*|x)Pr(y|x,c)Pr(x|c) \label{eq:Likelihood_Ind_ND},
\end{align}
asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj asldkfj  a;sdljf; asknvc covhoienr asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj lasdfiwe;q  a;sdljf; asknvc covhoienr asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj asldkfj alsdkjf alkdfj;lasdfiwe;q  a;sdljf; 

asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj asldkfj alsdkjf alkdfj;lasdfiwe;q  a;sdljf; asknvc covhoienr asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsdkjf alkdfj;lasdfiwe;q  a;sdljf; asknvc covhoienr asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj asldkfj alsdkjf alkdfj;lasdfiwe;q  a;sdljf; 
\begin{align}
  \!y^*|y &\sim \text{Bern}(y S_y + (1-y)(1-C_y)) \\
  \!x^*|x &\sim \text{Bern}(x S_x + (1-x)(1-C_x)).
\end{align}
asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj asldkfj alsdkjf  a;sdljf; asknvc covhoienr asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj asldkfj alsdkjf  asldkfj as;ldkjf  alsdkjf alkdfj;lasdfiwe;q  a;sdljf; 
\begin{align}
  L_m &= \prod_{i=1}^{n_m} \left\{ \sum_{y_i=0}^{y_i=1} \sum_{x_i=0}^{x_i=1} 
          Pr(y_i^*|y_i)Pr(x_i^*|x_i)Pr(y_i|x_i,c_{iy})Pr(x_i|c_{ix}) \right\}\\
  L_v &= \prod_{j=1}^{n_v} \left\{
          Pr(y_j^*|y_j)Pr(x_j^*|x_j)Pr(y_j|x_j,c_{jy})Pr(x_j|c_{jx}) \right\}
\end{align}
asknvc covhoienr asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj asldkfj alsdkjf alkdfj;lasdfiwe;q  a;sdljf; asknvc covhoienr asldkfj as;ldkjf a;lkdsfj asldkfj alsdkjf alkdfj;lasdfiwe;q  a;sdljf; asknvc covhoienr 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood. But you can do something locally with `\\[1em]` for example, or some other value.

Comment: The problem is not within the align environment so I don't think that will work. And, I have 100pages with equations on almost every page... to do this locally would be a pain.

Comment: @Sigur I added another example that I hope helps to explain the issue. This is my first posting so I am not sure how to show the compiled version in my question; I only know how to show the code.

Comment: I can see no uneven space in the first example, the second one gives `(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)`

Comment: `\doublespace` should be `\doublespacing`

Comment: to show the output just crop a screenshot of your viewer (you can use the snipping tool in windows) in this case you could use  an image editor to highlight the spacing that you want changing, as the spacing also seems to be even in the second example. (note the space above and below align is even, but not the same as the space between the rows of an align)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have shown a screenshot of what I would like to be fixed; maybe this will help to explain the spacing better. Thanks in advance!

Comment: note tex is mostly trying to preserve  or specify _baseline-to-baseline_ space so the red lines in your image are the wrong place,  the equations `\hat{x}=2` and `x=2` would normally be placed at the same place as tex sets the space to the baseline, the fact that the hat makes one equation taller doesn't mean that it is set lower, but if you draw a red line from the top of the hat to the previous paragraph it will be shorter than the red line to the equation without a hat.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You marked bottom of row to top of row space, but TeX does not make any attempt to keep that consistent and makes it rather hard to track that at all.

All TeX's vertical space calculations are based on maintaining baseline to baseline spacing, and that is consistent in your example.

In the smaller example here the baseline (red) spacing is maintained consequently the (green) space to the visible top of the formula is less if the formula has taller items on the first row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{5pt}
\begin{document}

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\begin{align}
  \hat{x}&=2^2
\end{align}

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\begin{align}
  x&=2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```